# Why is the algorithm complexity O(N*log(N+M))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

Consider the following [code](https://github.com/ZRonchy/Codility/blob/master/Lesson12/MinMaxDivision.java) (Github link)

The variable `min` is is at most `M` and the variable `max` is at most `M*N`
We run a binary search on the interval `[min, max]`. Each iteration we call to `divisionSolvable` which is `O(N)` so IMHO the overall complexity time is `O(N*log(NM))`.

Can you please explain why it isn't so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I really don't get the downvotes

Comment: @Elimination you don't present the code, for a start.

Comment: Well, I preferred linking to it as I'm not sure if it is legal to copy-pasting it

Comment: You should really read the guidelines of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question in Stackoverflow @Elimination

Comment: I honestly think it's a legitimate question (maybe I could rephrase my bottom line question)

Comment: Other than not copy-pasting the code I presented a clear question followed by my thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not looking at the link, note that `O(log(NM)) = O(log(N+M))`.
Indeed, for `N>=2` and `M>=2`, we have:

`log (N+M) < log(NM) = log(N) + log(M) < log(N+M) + log(N+M) = 2 log(N+M)`.

Complete that with the definition of `O()` which drops the constant.